Is the partition method of a custom Partitioner implementation required to be thread-safe in Apache Flink?
I am implementing a custom partitioner by extending the org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.Partitioner interface in Apache Flink. This requires me to override the partition method. My question is: do I need to ensure that the partition method is thread-safe?
I have searched online but have not found any definitive resources regarding the thread-safety requirements of the partition method when used in Flink's distributed processing environment. Since Flink jobs can run in parallel with multiple tasks potentially using the same partitioner instance, I am concerned about potential race conditions or inconsistent partitioning if the method is not thread-safe.
Any insights or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

No, there's no need to be concerned about thread safety with any of Flink's user functions. This is handled by the framework itself.
